# Cannot update contract in D365 for Finance and Operations

Tags: c#, odata, integration, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to update EmploymentEndDate in Contract in D365 Finance and Operation with oData using DataServiceCollection.
There is no error and it seems everything went well, but in the Contract EmploymentEndDate has no changes.
Similar code working well for other entities as Workers, Employee etc...

Has anyone experienced a similar situation, or to suggest other solution for this problem?

Thank You

```
public bool UpdateContractNG(string pPersonnelNumber, DateTime pEndEmploymentDate)
{
    try
    {
        Resources _contextUpd = Queries365.CreateErpContext();

        var queryUpd = from Employment
        in _contextUpd.Employments
                       where Employment.PersonnelNumber == pPersonnelNumber
                       orderby Employment.EmploymentStartDate descending
                       select Employment;

        DataServiceCollection<Employment> employmentCollection = new DataServiceCollection<Employment>(queryUpd);

        if (employmentCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (Employment emp in employmentCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"OLD EMPLOYMENT: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp)}");
                emp.EmploymentEndDate = pEndEmploymentDate.ToUniversalTime();

                _contextUpd.UpdateObject(emp);
                Console.WriteLine($"IN MEMORY CHANGED EMPLOYMENT: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp)}");

                break;
            }
        }

        DataServiceResponse response = _contextUpd.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties);

        // for testing (same context Check)
        Employment emp2 = Queries365.GetContract(_contextUpd, pPersonnelNumber);
        Console.WriteLine($"FROM SAME CONTEXT EMPLOYMENT: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp2)}");

        // new context refreshed data
        Resources _newContext = Queries365.CreateErpContext();
        Employment empAfterNew = Queries365.GetContract(_newContext, pPersonnelNumber);
        Console.WriteLine($"AFTER UPDATE NEW CONTEXT: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empAfterNew)}");

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error updating contract with Id {pPersonnelNumber} with Exception: {ex} ");
        return false;
    }
}

public static Resources CreateErpContext()
{
    // Resource
    string ODataEntityPath = ClientConfiguration.Default.UriString + "data";
    Uri oDataUri = new Uri(ODataEntityPath, UriKind.Absolute);
    Resources context = new Resources(oDataUri);
    context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(delegate (object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticationHeader = OAuthHelper.GetAuthenticationHeader(useWebAppAuthentication: true);
        e.RequestMessage.SetHeader(OAuthHelper.OAuthHeader, authenticationHeader);
    });

    return context;
}

public static Employment GetContract(Resources context, string personnelNumber)
{
    Employment emp = context.Employments.Where(x => x.PersonnelNumber == personnelNumber)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EmploymentStartDate).FirstOrDefault();

    return emp;
}
```

The output line: 
Console.WriteLine($"AFTER UPDATE NEW CONTEXT {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empAfterNew)}");
returns unexpected value for end date: "EmploymentEndDate":"2019-12-31T23:00:00+00:00".
And it is not updated in the system D365 for Finance and Opereations